# How to upload multiple images on Parse?

Tags: android, image, parse-platform

I need help with Parse Android API and images uploading/updating. User in my app can create event that has 1 or more images related to that event.  So, this images are stored as array object that have parse files.

User can edit images that he added for that event. So, user might want to delete image or to add a new image. So, there I have problem, how I can edit array to delete specific image.

My idea was to download all images on the phone, and when user add/delete image update it locally and then upload again all images to Parse and update that array of images, but it seems that is not working properly, since I get only one image uploaded.

How I can solve this problem, any idea is appreciated.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ImagesSingleton.getInstance().getBytesList().size(); i++) {
    String fileName = FileHelper.getFileName(getActivity(), ImagesSingleton.getInstance().getUrisList().get(i), "image");
    byte[] b = ImagesSingleton.getInstance().getBytesList().get(i);
    final ParseFile imgFile = new ParseFile(fileName, ImagesSingleton.getInstance().getBytesList().get(i));
    imgFile.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                listOfFiles.add(imgFile);
                if (listOfFiles.size() == ImagesSingleton.getInstance().getUrisList().size()) {
                    offer.put(ParseConstants.OFFER_PICTURES, listOfFiles);
                    offer.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(com.parse.ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null) {
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sucess saving", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                ImagesSingleton.getInstance().reset();
                                transferToRadar();
                            } else {
                                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getResources().getString(R.string.error) + e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is quite clear in documentation how to delete an element(s) from an Array column in Parse. You simply have to send the list of the files you want to be removed from the Array like this:

```
offer.removeAll(ParseConstants.OFFER_PICTURES, listOfFilesToRemove);
offer.saveInBackground();
```

Comment: When I read data from array column I get image URL and display it in the app.  I do not get ParseFile to add to list and then to remove it.

Comment: Try a collection with the following JSON format for a sample file `{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-987-photo.png","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/12345/tfss-987-photo.png"}`